# Unique profiles for each user role

Tags: 7, users

I have 3 different roles: Patient, Operator, Nurse. I have one registration form for all my users with basic information (applied via 'Account Settings'). I've been messing around with Profile2 to give each of roles a unique profile.

My problem is that I can't seem to stop Patients from having an Operator Profile and Nurses from having a Patient Profile. Is there a way for me to make the profiles unique to the roles?

I've also considered doing it exclusively in 'Account Settings' and restricting fields using Field Permissions?

I would like to do this so that alternations to the profiles is quick and easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restricting fields using field permissions would probably be the easiest way to do it; I've had to do something similar with Profile2 in the past and it involves overriding the access callback for profile pages, and checking that the user has a certain role.

Here's some sample code if you want to try it that way:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Ensure that category profiles are only visible if the user has the correct role
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/parent']['access callback'] = 'zylo_user_category_access';
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/tutor']['access callback'] = 'zylo_user_category_access';
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/school_staff']['access callback'] = 'zylo_user_category_access';
}

function MYMODULE_category_access($account, $type_name) {
  // First make sure the user has normal access to the page
  if (profile2_category_access($account, $type_name)) {
    // Check that the user has the correct role
    return in_array(str_replace('_', ' ', $type_name), $account->roles);
  } 

  return FALSE;
}
```

It isn't the prettiest but it does get the job done

Answer (score 0):

The best solution so far is [Managing account registration for multiple user types](http://www.grasmash.com/article/managing-account-registration-multiple-user-types) and you can see the result here: [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath).

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths per Profile2 profile type.